# List all the projects and all the groups

Tags: gitlab

What is the easiest method to list all the projects and groups in GitLab using my private token?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**If only your private token is available, you can only use the API:**

**PROJECTS**

Use the following command to request projects:

```bash
curl "https://<host>/api/v4/projects?private_token=<your private token>"
```

This will return you the first 20 entries. To get more you can add the paramater `per_page`

```bash
curl "https://<host>/api/v4/projects?private_token=<your private token>&per_page=100"
```

with this parameter you can request between `20`and `100` entries (see [REST API Pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/rest/#pagination) documentation).

If you now want all projects, you have to loop through the pages. To get to another page add the parameter `page`.

```bash
curl "https://<host>/api/v4/projects?private_token=<your private token>&per_page=100&page=<page_number>"
```

Now you may want to know how many pages there are. For that, add the `curl` parameter `--head`. This will not return the payload, but the header.

The result should look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 17:43:24 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 29428
Cache-Control: no-cache
Link: <request link>
Vary: Origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Next-Page: 2
X-Page: 1
X-Per-Page: 20
X-Prev-Page:
X-Request-Id: 80ecc167-4f3f-4c99-b09d-261e240e7fe9
X-Runtime: 4.117558
X-Total: 312257
X-Total-Pages: 15613
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

The two interesting parts here are `X-Total`and `X-Total-Pages`. The first is the count of available entries and the second the count of total pages.

I suggest to use python or some other kind of script to handle the requests and concat the results at the end.

If you want to refine the search, consult this wiki page:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#projects-api

**GROUPS**

For groups simply replace `projects` with `groups` in the curls.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/groups.html#list-groups

**UPDATE:**

Here is the official list of Gitlab API clients/wrappers: 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/#third-party-clients

I highly recommend using one of these.

Comment: Is there any reason why the curl doesn't return all the projects/pages that are there in Gitlab? I am an admin but using my token doesn't seem to be retrieving all the projects. However, if I look up on the UI, I can see all the projects.

Comment: If the token is the private one of an admin, you should get all projects or groups. Are you looping through pages, as described in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I loop through all the pages but for some reason, it doesn't show up.

Comment: Try to remove the private token from request and see if you are getting the same results. If it is so, you are only getting the public projects because the authentification has failed.

Comment: If you use an admin token and want to see **all** projects, you need to use the endpoint `/projects/visible` instead (same parameters). The projects endpoint only lists projects of which the user is a member. I don't think it's documented, but here is the PR: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/6681 @Bond

Comment: @hotfire42 The `/projects/visible` endpoint has been moved to a parameter. See the [newest docs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/api/projects.md) and this [commit](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/4e9e29d295fe2f8cd258cde4b65e244eb74a1ae6)

Comment: @secustor Yes sorry you are right, I just also noticed [this pr](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/9674), I was looking at api v3. It has also been implemented in the wrappers (at least the ruby one), but this might be helpful for people working with a not up-to-date gitlab instance.

Answer (score 8):

In bash for Gitlab API V4:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
GL_DOMAIN=""
GL_TOKEN=""
echo "" > gitlab_projects_urls.txt
for ((i=1; ; i+=1)); do
    contents=$(curl "$GL_DOMAIN/api/v4/projects?private_token=$GL_TOKEN&per_page=100&page=$i")
    if jq -e '. | length == 0' >/dev/null; then 
       break
    fi <<< "$contents"
    echo "$contents" | jq -r '.[].ssh_url_to_repo' >> gitlab_projects_urls.txt
done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

With [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli-examples.html) you can do this with:

```
$ gitlab project list                                                                                                 [6:53:23]
id: 58
path: project-omega

id: 56
path: sigma

id: 54
path: theta

...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small shell script to get all GitLab projects:

```bash
echo -n "Please enter private token: "
read -s PRIVATE_TOKEN
number_of_pages=$(curl -s --head "https://gitlab.example.org/api/v4/projects?private_token=$PRIVATE_TOKEN" | grep -i x-total-pages | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r\n')
for page in $(seq 1 $number_of_pages); do
    curl -s "https://gitlab.example.org/api/v4/projects?private_token=$PRIVATE_TOKEN&page=$page"
done
```

Replace `gitlab.example.org` with the hostname of your GitLab server.

Adjust it as needed; for example, this uses `jq` to get just the SSH repo URL for each project:

```bash
for page in $(seq 1 $number_of_pages); do
    curl -s "https://gitlab.example.org/api/v4/projects?private_token=$PRIVATE_TOKEN&page=$page" | jq -r '.[] | .ssh_url_to_repo'
done
```

Comment: The header for number of pages was `X-Total-Pages` for my setup, so grep should be case-insensitive: 
`number_of_pages=$(curl -s --head "https://gitlab.example.org/api/v4/projects?private_token=$PRIVATE_TOKEN" | grep -i x-total-pages | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '\r\n')`

Answer (score 1):

Using python You can easily List all the groups and the Projects.Below is the code which you can try to list the project and groups:

```
import os
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('http://gitlab_hostname.com', 'your_private_token')
groups = gl.groups.list()
projects = gl.projects.list()
all_projects = gl.projects.list(all=True)
all_groups=gl.groups.list(all=True)
print("All groups are:",all_groups)
length=len(all_projects)
i=0
while i < length:
    project = gl.projects.get(all_projects[i].id)
    print(project)
    i=i+1
```

Comment: I was hoping your answer worked - of course some time has passed since you posted - but with but if I add `all=True` to `projects = gl.projects.list(all=True)`, I get this "gitlab.exceptions.GitlabAuthenticationError: 401: 401 Unauthorized". I still wonder how I can do it.

Comment: @Lethargos Probably that is unrelated to this. Looks like you just don't have all the permissions access.

Comment: @LuigiLopez the issue was related to the fact that one repository was archived and gitlab wasn't allowing me to make any changes to it. By this occasion maybe other people who've across this issue find a solution here :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module we can get all groups and projects inside it. But if you have more than 20 groups or 20 projects inside of any group use pagination.

```
import gitlab
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com', private_token='Token')
groups = gl.groups.list()
for each in groups:
    group = gl.groups.get(each, lazy=True)
    project_lst=group.projects.list(as_list=False)  #pagination
    for item in project_lst:
    project_id = gl.projects.get(item.attributes['id'])
        ......................................
        ......................................
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests

# Configure access credentials
private_token = "YOUR_PRIVATE_TOKEN"
group_id = "YOUR_GROUP_ID"

# Variables for the loop
page = 1
per_page = 100

while True:
    # Create the URL to get a list of repositories from a group
    url = f"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/{group_id}/projects?include_subgroups=true&all_available=true&per_page={per_page}&page={page}"
    
    # Adds the access credentials to the request
    headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': private_token}
    
    # Makes the request and saves the response
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
    # Checks if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Prints the name of each repository in the response
        for repository in response.json():
            print(repository["name"])
    else:
        print("Error getting the list of repositories:", response.content)
        break
    
    # If there are no more repositories, exits the loop
    if len(response.json()) == 0:
        break

    # Increases the page for the next iteration
    page += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use the graphql endpoint

It is very efficient to use the graphql endpoint of gitlab because you can get structured json result in a very concise and resource efficient way, here are two exemplary steps to achieve the task of "listing all projects and groups":

1. Use the graphql-explorer to find your query
2. Send requests to the graphql endpoint with your developed query (python example)

### Use the graphql-explorer to find your query

1. Login to your gitlab instance (logging in is a required so that the queries also work on your private entities)
2. Go to the graphql explorer https://gitlab.com/-/graphql-explorer

After a bit of experimenting you would eventually come up with a query similar to this:

```json
query {
    user(username:"YourUserName") {
    groups {
      nodes {
        id
        parent {
          id
        }
        name
        descendantGroups {
          nodes {
            id
            name
          }
        }
        projects {
          nodes {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Send requests to the graphql endpoint with your developed query

Now you can e.g. via python post the above developed queries and work on the returned data:

```py
import requests

query = """
query {
    user(username:"YourUserName") {
    groups {
      nodes {
        id
        parent {
          id
        }
        name
        descendantGroups {
          nodes {
            id
            name
          }
        }
        projects {
          nodes {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
"""
url = 'https://gitlab.com/api/graphql?private_token=your_private_token'
response = requests.post(url, json={'query': query})
data = response.json()
# work on data ...
```

Happy coding

Answer (score -1):

You also have the [`glab repo list` command](https://man.archlinux.org/man/glab-repo-list.1.en), from the [`gitlab-org/cli`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli) official GitLab CLI project.

Example (from "[GitLab: glab official CLI tool for repository operations](https://fabianlee.org/2022/12/13/gitlab-glab-official-cli-tool-for-repository-operations/)" by [Fabian Lee](https://fabianlee.org)):

```bash
# create public repo
$ glab repo create mytest123 --public
✓ Created repository Fabian Lee / mytest123 on GitLab: https://gitlab.com/fabianlee/mytest123

# list all personal repo
$ glab repo list
Showing 1 of 1 projects (Page 1 of 1)
fabianlee/mytest123 git@gitlab.com:fabianlee/mytest123.git
```

You do have the option `-a`, `--all[=false]`: List all projects on the instance.